# Geocoder without MapView

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to create a response from my longitude and latitude results into addresses in plain String form.  When I run the debugger I throw an exception Service Unavailable I am assuming because I have not entered the API key.  My question is where do I put the API key in without creating an xml file that creates a mapview that is not used?

Comment: for `Geocoder API` no need of API key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Note: Answer changed based on comments)*

I originally assumed that the [Google APIs Addon](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/) is needed for `Geocoder` to work because the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) states that the class uses a backend service that is not provided in the core android framework.

After further investigation, I've found that the Google APIs Add-On is not required.  Rather, the target device must support the backend service and I assume this means it needs to be a device that includes the Play Store app or maybe the Google Maps app or both?

Either way, to prove the theory, I made a simple test app that doesn't use the Google APIs Add-On yet it still works on my Galaxy Nexus device. If I run it on the emulator however (which, of course, doesn't include Play Store or Google Maps), it throws `Service not Available`.

Comment: If you have no Map, then you shouldn't even need the google addon. `Geocoder` is core framework.

Comment: The `GeoCoder` class is core framework but it requires a background service that isn't - I will update answer to make this clear.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have installed the the google API and in my manifest I did put the  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> <uses-library<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />.  When I run the program it throws and exception.

Comment: No problem :-) What is the exception that you get?

Comment: The exception I get says Service Unavailable.  I am wondering if that is because I have not put the API key somewhere?

Comment: Hmm, strange.  Maybe I am mistaken and the API key is required to use the add-on, rather than just for MapView.  I'll knock-up a test-project to confirm or deny this and report back here soon.

Comment: I am confused now!  I have made a test app and `Geocoder` works fine without using the Google Maps addon.  Yet, a few weeks ago I had the same problem as you ('Service Unavailable') so I added the Maps Addon (because I needed the `MapView` anyway) and it worked from them on, hence the assumption that the Maps addon was required).

Comment: Are you using the emulator?  I think what's happening is the target device needs to support the backend service and that might only be provided by 'Google Experience' devices that include the Android Market/Play Store.  Can you try it on a device with Play Store installed?

Comment: I am not using the emulator for the testing.  I am using my connected android phone that has Play Store installed.  This is what confuses me.  I am thoroughly stumped.

Comment: Hmm, please provide details of the device you are testing on (Android OS Version, device make and model, etc).

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

       try {
  List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
  if(addresses != null) {
   Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
   StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
   for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
   }
   myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
  }
  else{
   myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
  }
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");
 }
```

two permissions in my manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have essentially the same code and my error gets thrown on the first line  List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1); Which is the same as yours.  I keep getting the service unavailable.  I have both permissions in the manifest as well.  Thank you for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line of

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
```

Instead, Try this code...

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
```

They are the same code, but I've solved the problem with this.
But, this was toooooo wierd.

hmm..